# How to specify SERDEPROPERTIES and TBLPROPERTIES when creating Hive table via prestosql

Tags: hive, presto, trino

I'm trying to follow the examples of [Hive connector](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#examples) to create hive table. I can write HQL to create a table via beeline. But wonder how to make it via prestosql.

Given table

```
CREATE TABLE hive.web.request_logs (
  request_time varchar,
  url varchar,
  ip varchar,
  user_agent varchar,
  dt varchar
)
WITH (
  format = 'CSV',
  partitioned_by = ARRAY['dt'],
  external_location = 's3://my-bucket/data/logs/'
)
```

1. How to specify `SERDEPROPERTIES` like `separatorChar` and `quoteChar`?
2. How to specify `TBLPROPERTIES` like `skip.header.line.count`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Presto you do this like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name( ... columns ... )
WITH (format='CSV', csv_separator='|', skip_header_line_count=1);
```

You can list all supported table properties in Presto with

```
SELECT * FROM system.metadata.table_properties;
```

Comment: Thank you! Just want to add more info from slack thread about where Hive table properties are defined: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/e80ddadb08a18576b413fa3088db9b990dc12ffb/presto-hive/src/main/java/io/prestosql/plugin/hive/HiveTableProperties.java#L49-L70